# Error while use authentication from AD server

Tags: java

```
package mypack;

import java.util.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;

public class ADCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"LDAP://myad.com:385"); 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"DIGEST-MD5"); 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"MY_USER_NAME"); 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "MY_PASSWORS");  
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            ctx.close();
        } catch(NamingException ne) {
            System.out.println("Error authenticating user:");
            System.out.println(ne.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("OK, successfully authenticating user");
    }
}
```

Getting Error:

> javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: 
>   LdapErr: DSID-0C09043E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 0, vece.

please help

Comment: add LDAP tag to the questions!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=5266

> When testing authentication to an Active Directory server, you may see
>   this error:
>
> Authentication Error: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr:
>   DSID-0C09043E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 0, vece].
>
> Resolution or Workaround:
>
> This can occur if the Host Type in the Remote Domain configuration is
>   incorrect.  Change the Host Type to Active Directory (or vice versa):

Also check
http://www.websina.com/bugzero/faq/ldap-error-code-49.html

> A: This error is caused by the wrong setting of
>   java.naming.security.principal.
>
> A full DN must be used here, something like:
>
> CN=FName
>   LName,OU=OrgUnit_the_user_stored_in,DC=Domain_name,DC=Domain_suffix

Comment: And then use Google, then Bing and so on